# How To store image view id's in array and set image resource on specific image view element

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-resources

[imgv is a array contain id's of image view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9c6w.png)

How do I store ImageView IDs in an array and set Image resource on a specific ImageView element?

Comment: Can you mention what have you tried?
Also, you can use an int array to store the id of the imageview and later retrieve the view to set the resource. But you need to be careful since the imageview might not be available any more

Comment: Please add your code as text, not image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use setImageResource on int array this method must be used on ImageView object

> Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.

**More explanation in documentation** [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int))

**Simply you can do something like this**

```
    int[] array = {R.drawable.imag_view_1,R.drawable.imag_view_3,R.drawable.imag_view_2};

    imageView.setImageResource(array[0]);
```